# how to write to the logcat in android studio inside compose function

Tags: android-studio, logging, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to write in the log inside a Compose function but is not working.

I have this @Composable function:

```
@Composable
```

fun MainScreen(navController: NavHostController){

```
Log.d("test", "Entered MainScreen")

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()

) {

    Text(text = "Menu:", fontSize = 22.sp)

    Button(
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate("HouseScreen")

        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

    ) {
        Text(text = "Inventory")
    }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate("AboutScreen")

        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

    ) {
        Text(text = "About")
    }

}
```

}

I already added in my Gradle:

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
    buildConfig = true
}
```

I only see this:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (23621) for package com.mastercoding.houseinventory ----------------------------
```

--------- beginning of kernel
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (23621) for package com.mastercoding.houseinventory ----------------------------

I am running on Debug mode.

For testing I added more instances of Log code in the beginning of the Application

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("test", "Entered MainActivity")
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        Log.getStackTraceString(e)
        exitProcess(2)
    }
    setContent {
        HouseInventoryTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {

                Log.d("test", "Entered Theme")

                val mContext = LocalContext.current
                val db = InventoryDB.getInstance(mContext)
                val repository  = InventoryRepository(db)
                val myViewModel = InventoryViewModel(repository = repository)
```

But nothing was written in the Logcat.

Comment: So the UI from MainScreen is displayed, but the log message is not printed?

Comment: That is Correct! That is the entry/first Composable.

Comment: Well that's weird.. Logging works inside composable functions, I can't see why it wouldn't in your case. Can you see your other logs? You can try logging your MainActivity onCreate or something...